# How to reduce the following problem to Nim problem using Grundy numbers?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

The problem is similar the Nim problem except now for every non empty pile, either player can remove 0 items from that pile and have it count as their move; however, this move can only be performed once per pile by either player. Lets call this move as a zero move.

For example, let's say pile i initially has 2 items in it. If player A decides to use a Zero-Move on this pile , then neither A nor B can perform another Zero-Move on pile ; that said, either player is free to perform a Zero-Move on any other non-empty pile that hasn't had a Zero-Move performed on it yet.

How can I convert this problem to the standard nim problem using Grundy Numbers?

Is it solvable(telling which player will win) without using Grundy Numbers?

Comment: I was able to figure out that if a zero move has not been made on the pile then after applying grundy number , it behaves like a pile having 1 extra element....So since initially all the piles don't have zero move made on them.... Therefore I add 1 element to each pile.. Then if I calculate xor of the piles, and if it turns out to be non zero ,  does that mean that the first player would win?

Comment: A better way to specify this is rule to specify that in addition to the normal pieces, each pile has an additional red piece that may only be removed if all other pieces of the pile have been removed in previous moves. That way you avoid having two types of empty piles that are only distinguished by the knowledge of past moves. Note that this is *not* equivalent to just adding another normal piece, as that would allow to empty a pile at once, which is equivalent in your game to emptying the heap while forbidding the zero move on that newly empty heap, which isn't a valid move in your game.

Comment: @celtschk How would you find the Grundy Number associated with such a pile? The red piece can occupy k positions, where k is the number of pieces in a pile.

Comment: The piles are not ordered (that's why they are called piles), therefore the position of the red piece in the pile isn't relevant. If you want to think of the piles as rows, you can just assume the red piece is always the leftmost one.

Comment: @celtschk While calculating the Grundy Number associated with such a pile/in the sequence of events, won't its order be important? Because one can choose to use the zero move at the very beginning, while also opting not to use the zero move at all.

Comment: @celtschk Also, you said that "each pile has an additional red piece that may only be removed if all other pieces of the pile have been removed in previous moves." However, if all the other pieces of the pile have been removed, the red piece may no longer be removed, since a zero move can only be made on non-empty piles.

Comment: @AshishGupta: Sorry, I had misread "empty pile" where you wrote "non-empty pile". So you may remove the red piece if the other pieces have *not* yet been all removed. But anyway, there is no order on the pile; either the pile still has its red piece, or it doesn't. If you decide to do the zero move at the beginning, you are left with a pile that no longer contains a red piece right after the first move. If you opt to not do the zero move, the red piece remains there until the end. In any case, the numbers of normal and red pieces completely determine the game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50603/discussion-between-ashish-gupta-and-celtschk).

Comment: Why don't I have access to the chat?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67788/755.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer mentioned above is incorrect.It is clear that if pile size is zero no move is possible.g(0)=0
If  you try to build a solution bottom up  it turns out that if n is even the grundy number is n-1 and when it is odd the grundy is n+1.

Proof:
Grundy number of a state is the smallest positive integer that cannot be reached in one valid move.
When the pile size is zero the grundy number is 0 as no moves including the zero move is possible.
For a given pile size n we actually have two states:

- N is the size but no zero move is available.This is analogous to grundy number of the standard nim with grundy number equal to n.
- N is the size but zero move is available.Well,it turns out from this state you can reach the state mentioned above and all other states with a zero move remaining for size k < n.

Just try working your way bottom up.For n=1(with zero move left) you can reach n=1(no zero move left) and n=0(empty pile).Therefore,g(1)=2.For n=2 one cannot reach the state n=1(no zero move left) as both making a zero move and removing blocks simultaneously is not possible.g(2)=1.

Comment: could you elaborate more that assumption? Why does if the number is even or odd have something to do with the fact that the player has used the zero move before?

Comment: I have edited my answer.You can have a look at it now.

Comment: say iT -> pile size of length i with zero move left, iF -> pile size of length i with no zero move left then we can do the following: mex(0) = {0}, mex(1F) -> {0}, mex(1T) -> {mex(1F), 0} -> {1,0} -> 2, mex(2F) -> mex{1, 0} -> 2, mex(2T) -> mex{mex(2F), mex(1T), 0}-> mex{2, 2, 0} -> 1 and so on. Inductively we can show that minimum excluded value for I is either i-1 if i is even, or i + 1 if i is odd